# Expand formula next to a spilled range

Tags: excel, range

Here's what I want to do:

In column A, there's a UNIQUE function that spills out data from my database.
In column B, I want a SUMIF formula to expand or retract depending of the lenght of the spilled rang in column A.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`Is this possible?`

Yes, It is possible.

---

Now to answer the implied question of "How?".

D2 has:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A13)
```

I then used:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2#)
```

to return the array.

[image]